# AWS CDK Init for an existing project

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-cdk

I'm trying to initialize the AWS CDK on a new website I just created via Visual Studio.

But when I run the init commmand I get the error: *`cdk init` cannot be run in a non-empty directory*

```
❯ cdk init app --language=csharp
`cdk init` cannot be run in a non-empty directory!
```

The [CDK Workshop](https://cdkworkshop.com/40-dotnet/20-create-project/100-cdk-init.html) uses the example of starting from scrach (in an empty directory).

**Is it possible to initialize the CDK inside an existing solution/project?**

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/

Comment: @jdweng - anything specific I should be looking for?  I'm not using the dotnet cli in this case, trying to use the Aws cdk tool

Answer (score 10, accepted):

cdk init creates a basic structure and a skeleton, such as an app and subdirectory in which it creates a stack.

You can run it in an empty directory, back up the files you will override, and then copy an actual cdk application/project (such as workshop one) into it.

I use this way to create another CDK project when I re-use the existing one.

Comment: Using the [--generate-only](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/cli.html#cli-ref) flag makes this task easier as it only creates the bare minimum files necessary to make a project a "CDK" project.

Comment: @mon By "back up" you mean just "delete", since you won't be putting those files back anyway?

Comment: @MEMark, basically yes, but preserve them so that we can compare just in case CDK has made some changes.

Answer (score 5):

At the moment there is no way to execute `cdk init` in a non-empty directory. This is a safety net against cluttering a directory with the CDK files where they might not be wanted.

That said, there is no practical reason a command flag to override this protection couldnt be added. You could consider putting in a [feature-request](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/new?labels=feature-request%2C%20needs-triage&template=feature-request.md&title=%5Bmodule%5D%20) on the repo.

Comment: Thanks @noah, filled a feature request:  https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/9609